# If an activity is killed, does the AsyncTask live on?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I think I know the answer to this, but does an AsyncTask continue to live on once its calling Activity has been `finish()`ed?

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your data is processing.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        finish();
    }
```

Edit: so far two different answers :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The AsyncTask is tied to a UI thread and if the Activity is finished the async task is canceled.

*[update]* - Hackbod's comment below is correct. It should be noted that AsyncTasks are meant to be short lived and as such not worry so much about this issue. An AsycTask is only truly gone when it is completed OR the process is killed which may or may not happen after finish is called.

Comment: I think you're right (as stated in the docs): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#Class_Overview

Comment: That phrasing is not so good.  AsyncTask is completely independent from an Activity; you have to manage them together.  An activity being *finished* does not do anything to any AsyncTasks, unless you are cleaning them up from onDestroy().  On the other hand, if an activity's process is being killed while it is in the background, then certainly the AsyncTask will also be killed as well, as part of the entire process disappearing.

Comment: so do we need to check if activity is still alive before making ui changes inside _onPostExecute()_ ?

Answer (score 1):

It keeps running until the `onPostExecute` finishes.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced some weirdness with Async Tasks where if an activity is killed by the OS and when the app resumes, the AsyncTasks sometimes do not run at all. I am unsure why they get into this state. If you execute your AsyncTasks in your own executor thread, this does not happen. I might be running into some odd circumstance. Thought it might be useful to post here anyway :).

Comment: I am having the same problem. when I resume the asynkTask doesnt work . how to solve this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My solution, as I mentioned above, was to use an executor and pass the AsyncTask into it. The method you are looking for is AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor() - Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Async task keeps running untill he onPostExecute() is finished.

try it by putting a toast on finish()  and  onPostExecute() to see which toast is shown first.

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask are not bounded to any life cycle method of Activity or Service.

It keeps running in a separate thread until the onPostExecute() gets executed in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Async Tasks have no effect of the Activity lifecycle or any configuration changes. They keep on running till onPostExecute() method has been called.

One should use Services for long running operations instead.